# Tools not working

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects

I apologise for posting the same question, but nobody seems to be active. I have nowhere else to look but my rotating tool isn't working. I'm trying to make this an efforted question but I really don't know what to do. My rotation tool is doing this:

https://gyazo.com/e7639bcb68cb1c6a57ed61ffab05f9c8

when I try to move an object up it just goes in these directions.    <---->

thanks. (oh and im a complete noob so I don't really know what these tools are.)

Comment: From what you offered it seems to be your pivot point. If you select the top edge with xray mode enabled to grab the whole outline, select shift s, cursor to selected In edit mode. Then in object mode Select set origin to 3d cursor. Also make sure your axis is set to global.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner so I don't even know what this stuff is. I feel bad admitting it :(

Comment: Hi. Instead of asking the same question twice you should address the problems with your first question. If you need to add more details you can use the edit link below it. Thanks.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: sir I have nowhere else to look what else am I supposed to do??

Comment: My first question was that my rotation tool wouldn't go up! It moves left to right no matter the color I click. For example, If I drag the white circle to tilt the head, it just goes <-->. Im a young beginner and I don't understand the concepts of this! Can you please be more reasonable and HELP me? I am stressed out and I've been struggling with this for- hmm.. 2 DAYS? There are NO videos online and I can't find anything. So if you want me to stop duplicating my questions, why don't you sit down and take the time to actually answer them.